# How do I use the response from the ReadLine in the SQL select statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to find Order Numbers based on First and Last name that the user enters into the application. I am extremely new to C# and I am just trying to write a simple program for a user to quickly pull order #s.

Thanks In Advance,

Jared

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Name");
            String FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Last Name");
            String LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            SqlConnection conn = new      SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PropertyTax;Integrated Security=true"); 
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select First_Name, Order_Number From [PropertyTax].[dbo].[Sheet1$] Where First_Name = FirstName and Last_Name = LastName ", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Parameters property of SqlCommand.  You can read the MSDN for it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Essentially, you need to add a parameter for the input you got from the user like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName);
```

and in your query, you need to update your statement to use the new @ variable:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select First_Name, Order_Number From [PropertyTax].[dbo].[Sheet1$] Where First_Name = @FirstName and Last_Name = @LastName", conn);
```